# How to convert number to a date in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have to transform a number (0-364) to date starting
from January 01, 2013. Example: 00 = Jan 01, 2013 or 45 = 15
Feb, 2013; 364= 31 Dec, 2013

Comment: Don't forget the leap year cases.

Answer (score 4):

If you construct a `new Date`, but specify a `day` value that is too large, the day value will 'overflow' and increment the months. As such, you can do the following:

```
days = 1;
date = new Date(2013, 0, days);
// => Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)

days = 46;
date = new Date(2013, 0, days);
// => Fri Feb 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)

days = 365;
date = new Date(2013, 0, days);
// => Tue Dec 31 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1100 (EST)
```

Note that using this method, `days` starts from 1 for the start of the year. If you want `days == 0` to produce `01 Jan, 2013`, you will need to use: `new Date(2013, 00, days + 1);`

Comment: +1 nice .. you learn something new every day :-)

Comment: Perfect solution imo, just one note: the requested year was *2013*, but it doesn't matter a lot, moreover you should do `days + 1` or providing `0` as days will return in 31st of December of the previous year :)

Comment: @LightStyle Good point, I updated my example to reflect 0 meaning 01-Jan

Comment: i have try like this but my boss want only Feb 15 2013

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this :

```
// initialize to start of the year
var dt= new Date(2013,00,01); 
// add the required number of days to date
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + <number of days>);
```

where `<number of days>` is your variable

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tn59U/)

Comment: i have try like this but my boss want only Feb 15 2013

Comment: @AlinaFloreaHodoroaba then look at the documentation and work out for your self how to present the date how you require -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getTime():

```
var days = xxx;
var date = new Date(2013, 0, 1);
var res = date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
console.log( new Date(res) );
```